# Renaming project gives med code signing error

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-signing, codesign, ios-provisioning

I just renamed my project and also in the project.pbxproj renamed my product to the new name.

Now I am getting codesigning error when trying to debug on the phone. How come and how do I fix this? I have defined the profile to the same as on my phone for "debug"-ing.

It works well on the simulator. It didn't work before changing the product name either. I have also cleared the file history.

Inlcuding the log here:

```
Fri Jul 30 12:51:36 unknown SpringBoard[28] <Warning>: Killing <SBApplication:0x6343510> com.iAndApp.BlockPop  activate:  deactivate:  for app installation
Fri Jul 30 12:51:37 unknown SpringBoard[28] <Warning>: Reloading and rendering all application icons.
Fri Jul 30 12:51:42 unknown com.apple.debugserver-48[2630] <Warning>: debugserver-48 for armv6 Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Apple, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Fri Jul 30 12:51:42 unknown com.apple.debugserver-48[2630] <Warning>: Connecting to com.apple.debugserver service...
Fri Jul 30 12:51:42 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: lockbot[2617] Builtin profile: debugserver (sandbox)
Fri Jul 30 12:51:44 unknown SpringBoard[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID(20af30) uilock state: 1 -> 0
Fri Jul 30 12:51:44 unknown SpringBoard[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID(2277a0) device bootloaded
Fri Jul 30 12:51:45 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.iAndApp.BlockPop[0x5ab4]) Spawned and waiting for the debugger to attach before continuing...
Fri Jul 30 12:51:45 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Error>: (UIKitApplication:com.iAndApp.BlockPop[0x5ab4]) posix_spawn("/var/mobile/Applications/CB93DCE9-6063-4486-9E48-E502D748CC3A/BlockPop.app/BlockPopLite", ...): Permission denied
Fri Jul 30 12:51:45 unknown SpringBoard[28] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 2631: (os/kern) failure
Fri Jul 30 12:51:45 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.iAndApp.BlockPop[0x5ab4]) Exited with exit code: 1
Fri Jul 30 12:51:45 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.iAndApp.BlockPop[0x5ab4]) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2147483647 seconds
Fri Jul 30 12:51:45 unknown SpringBoard[28] <Warning>: Application 'BlockPopLite' exited abnormally with exit status 1
Fri Jul 30 12:52:15 unknown com.apple.debugserver-48[2630] <Error>: error: failed to lookup the process ID for CFBundleIdentifier com.iAndApp.BlockPop.
Fri Jul 30 12:52:15 unknown com.apple.debugserver-48[2630] <Warning>: error: failed to launch process (null): unknown error.
Fri Jul 30 12:52:15 unknown com.apple.debugserver-48[2630] <Warning>: 1 [0a46/1403]: error: ::read ( 6, 0x3809f4, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Fri Jul 30 12:52:45 unknown SpringBoard[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID(20af30) uilock state: 0 -> 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Niklas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did as many other did, I recreated the project and moved the content to the new project. Some lessons learned that may be valuable for others:

1. First, I tried to create an empty project and then copied all content by just dragging the files (classes, sound files, xib files, etc.). That didn't work, complaints about that it couldn't load the files. May also have to do with that I changed name of the project earlier, that's actually when all problems started.
2. I created a new project that's window-based. Could be my incompetence, but I didn't manage to get the first view loaded properly and, hence, ended up with a grey first view. I created all files and xibs and copied the code from to the newly created class files. I copied/pasted all graphical objects in my xib and configured everything as they're supposed to be (class associations, actions, outlets, etc).
3. I created a new view-based application with exactly the name I was going to use for my app. By doing this I get the delegate AND controller file for free, and I was hoping that some of the assocations I failed to do was going to come for free now. Differently from 2 above, I now added my files by rigth-clicking on Classes/Other Resources/etc.->Add->Existing Files. The only thing I dragged from my old project was png-files. I cannot really explain why, but I guess that some associations happens behind the scenes when xCode creates the delegate and controller files which I couldn't controll when creating a windows based project, due to my incompetence or how xCode works.

Cheers,
Niklas

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The Console log showed:

> Mon Dec  6 10:43:46 (deviceName) com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:(appId)[0x7f1b][2763]) : ((appId)[0x7f1b]) posix_spawn("/var/mobile/Applications/427DC185-7DD3-4286-B73E-9B650798A37D/(appName).app/CO", ...): Permission denied

This only occurred when running/debugging with XCode debugger. The app would not crash when launching from the launcher.

I tried reinstalling certificates with no success.

It appeared to me that the problem was with the debugger connecting.

I deleted the application, and on the next run/debug with XCode the problem had gone away!

Answer (score 0):

I am using this script to rename my iOS project. https://github.com/ytbryan/rename

Remember to update your Xcode scheme too.